# Loosing active class of bootstrap thumbnail when clicking any other control of the page

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Loosing css of bootstrap thumbnai link when clicking any other control or page itself 
     CSS-

```
a.thumbnail:hover,
a.thumbnail:focus,
a.thumbnail.active
 {
  border-color: gray;
  color:#003300;
  background-color:#ADDEA
}
```

Comment: So what is your question. How to leave the anchor as active even after it loses focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the below jQuery to force the active class to the current anchor.

```
$('a.thumbnail').click(function(){
    //Remove from active from a.thumbnail
    $('a.thumbnail').removeClass('active');
    //add it back to current active item
    $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/cbrr5mwc/

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem.